# A question related to Method of steepest descent i am unable to think about

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, asymptotics, approximation

I have a question in method of steepest descent

> Method as written from where I am studying -> If w is a complex function such that w'($z_0$) =0 and w"($z_0$) =|w"($z_0$)| $ e^{i\alpha_0}$$\neq$ 0.

Denote $\theta$ by the direction of line $\Delta$ passing through $z_0$ that is arg(z-$z_0$) =$\theta$ where z belongs to $\Delta$ .

I am looking for a proof of next line ->
Then, there are exactly two paths of greatest descent from Re(w) in $z_0$ of which the tangents of the directions $z_0$ are $\theta_+$= π/2 - $\alpha_0$/2 and $\theta_-$= -π/2 - $\alpha_0$ /2.

How the two paths of greatest descent have exactly these two $\theta$'s .

Can someone please explain!!

Comment: Which research paper? Which page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ref. 1 is considering

$$\int_L g(z)e^{nw(z)} \mathrm{d}z~=~\ldots, \qquad n~>~0, \tag{4} $$

which is a standard situation for the [method of steepest descent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_of_steepest_descent).
Let $z_0$ be a [stationary point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stationary_point) $w^{\prime}(z_0)=0$. Knowing the behaviour of the exponential function, the direction of steepest descent in the complex $w$-plane has [argument](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argument_(complex_analysis)) that belongs to $\pi +2\pi\mathbb{Z}$.
The Taylor expansion reads 
$$ w(z)~=~w(z_0)+ \frac{1}{2}w^{\prime\prime}(z_0)(z-z_0)^2 + O((z-z_0)^3). $$
The quadratic Taylor term $\frac{1}{2}w^{\prime\prime}(z_0)(z-z_0)^2$ in the exponent has by definition argument $\alpha_0+2\theta.$ If this argument belongs to $\pi +2\pi\mathbb{Z}$, then the corresponding angle
$$\theta~\in~ \frac{\pi}{2}-\frac{\alpha_0}{2}+\pi\mathbb{Z}$$ is the direction of steepest descent in the complex $z$-plane, cf. the quote from Ref. 1.

References:

1. T. Rivoal, *Irrationalite d'au moins un des neuf nombres zeta(5),zeta(7),...,zeta(21),* [arXiv:math/0104221](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0104221)
   ; p. 6-7.

Comment: I am not able to understand the line " Knowing the behavior of exponential function " and after this . What property of exponential function are you using. Can you please elaborate?

Comment: I updated the answer.

Comment: why must argument of n/2 w"($z_0$) $(z-z_0)^2 $  belong to π +2πZ , can you please explain?

Comment: I updated the answer.